# Detect AngularJS Changes in Iframe

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, iframe

We have a site in an iframe in which all changes are made using AngularJS, so the URL never changes after the page has been initially loaded. Somehow we need to detect the changes/redirections made within the iframe, but we can only catch the initial load, and nothing after that. Is it even possible to detect these changes within the iframe?

Answer (score -1):

If you working on iframe and as page initially loaded and you want the changes through angularjs. You can do like this..

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
<iframe id="myIframe" src="/angular/iframe/frame2.html"
    onLoad="onLoad()" />
```

Here as in Html you can add onLoad method and call from controller

```
function onLoad() {
    var ifrm = document.getElementById('myIframe');
    angular.element(ifrm).scope().onIframeLoad(ifrm.src);
}
```

This how angularjs will show pop up on page load